# WildFly 10.1 Failed to create journal-datasource to store message

Tags: wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

I'm using an old version of WildFly (10.1) which uses the ActiveMQ Artemis that comes with it, and I was trying to switch the store method from a store in the file system to store in the database (and I know that the ActiveMQ Artemis default way to store the is better).

So I'm using this configuration for ActiveMQ Artemis:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
     <server name="default">
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

and than using `jboss-cli.bat` (I'm using Windows), I run this command:

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=vmvanz:write-attribute(name=journal-datasource, value=ExampleDS)
```

And I get this error:

```
{
"outcome" => "failed",
"failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0201: Unknown attribute 'journal-datasource'",
"rolled-back" => true
}
```

I try the same command in WildFly 14 and work. I read the [documentation from 10.1](https://docs.wildfly.org/13/Admin_Guide.html#Messaging_JDBC_Store_for_Messaging_Journal) and it show the same command line.

Does someone knows if this is a problem from this version or know some other way to configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WildFly 10.1 doesn't support the `journal-datasource` attribute. It ships with version `1.0` of the ActiveMQ messaging configuration schema. This is specified in your configuration here:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
```

The `journal-datasource` attribute wasn't available until version `2.0` of the ActiveMQ messaging configuration schema which first appeared in **WildFly 11**.

Also, the documentation you linked is for WildFly 13. This is visible in the URL:

```
https://docs.wildfly.org/13/Admin_Guide.html#Messaging_JDBC_Store_for_Messaging_Journal
```